# Median of medians select algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, selection, median-of-medians

for the last few days I've been trying really hard to write this algorithm but without success. The code works and most of the time it gives me the right result but there are some cases where it fails. For example with this array {3, 8, 1, 9, 10, 7, 6, 2, 5, 4} and k = 6 it should give me 6 as result but it gives me 7. Can someone help me? I can't figure out what's the problem.

Here is the code:

```
class MOMSelect {

static int median(int a[], int i, int n) {
    if(i <= n)
        Arrays.sort(a, i, n);
    else
        Arrays.sort(a, n, i);
    return a[n/2];
}

static int medianOfMediansSelect(int a[], int left, int right, int k) {
    int n = right - left + 1;
    int i;
    int[] medians = new int[(n + 4) / 5];
    for (i = 0; i < n/5; i++) {
        medians[i] = median(a, left + i * 5, 5);
    }
    if (i*5 < n) {
        medians[i] = median(a,left + i * 5, n % 5);
        i++;
    }
    int medianOfMedians = (i == 1)? medians[i - 1]: median(medians, 0, medians.length);
    int pivotIndex = partition(a, left, right, medianOfMedians);
    if (pivotIndex == k - 1) {
        return a[pivotIndex];
    }
    else if (pivotIndex - left > k - 1) {
        return medianOfMediansSelect(a, left, pivotIndex - 1, k);
    }
    else {
        return medianOfMediansSelect(a, pivotIndex + 1, right, k);
    }
}

static void swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int temp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = temp;
}

static int partition(int[] a, int left, int right, int x) {
    int i;
    for (i = left; i < right; i++)
        if (a[i] == x)
            break;
    swap(a, i, right);
    i = left;
    for (int j = left; j <= right - 1; j++) {
        if(a[j] <= x) {
            swap(a, i, j);
            i++;
        }
    }
    swap(a, i, right);
    return i;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a[] = {3, 8, 1, 9, 10, 7, 6, 2, 5, 4};
    int n = a.length;
    int k = 1;
    System.out.println(medianOfMediansSelect(a, 0, n - 1, k));
}
}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: Arrays.sort() receives (array, beginIndex, endIndex), not (array, beginIndex, count), as you are trying to use it.

Comment: You should debug in that case you could discover what @ardenit said by yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I modified your `median` method to correct the problem. You should check `Arrays.sort` method for a clear understanding.

Now it gives `6`, for `k=6`.

Here is it,

```
   static int median(int a[], int i, int n)
   {
      Arrays.sort(a, i, i + n - 1);

      return a[i + n / 2];
   }
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but now the program throws this exception "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: fromIndex(0) > toIndex(-1)" for k = 8

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved. Further than my bad understanding of the Arrays.sort() method there was a stupid mistake on the if stucture where I check the pivotPosition value on the method `medianOfMediansSelect()`

More precisely on this line

`else if (pivotIndex - left > k - 1) {`

I should have done like this

`else if (pivotIndex > k - 1) {`

Comment: Glad to know it works, I was thinking to work on it during the weekend.